# Is there a way to get notes from iOS default note application programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to get notes from iOS default note application programmatically? Couldn't find any answer anywhere.

Comment: AFAIK you are *unable* to get them so far...

Comment: No, this is not possible. Apple does not provide any API to interact with the notes app.

Comment: @Baig Has Apple provided an API to access Notes on an iOS device since you made this comment?

Comment: @DanielBrower have not seen it yet.